# Bootstrap 4 - large rounded corners only on top half

Tags: bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4, they have the classes `.rounded-top` and `.rounded-lg` I want to be able to create a large rounded corner on only the top half. If I add `.rounded-top` it rounds just the top which is what I want, but I also want it to be large. If I add `.rounded-lg` it rounds all the corners.

How can I round just the top with a large round?

Answer (score 0):

You can try global classes:

```
 .rounded-top-left {
        border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
    }
    .rounded-top-right {
        border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
    }
    .rounded-bottom-left {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem;
    }
    .rounded-bottom-right {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
    }
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this without custom CSS classes, and just using the Bootstrap classes, but seems like it may not be possible.

Comment: Not sure with bootstrap but you can use tailwind css if possible. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-radius